# Not working in Python 2, Python 2 vs Python 3 Inheriting a wrapper

Tags: python, inheritance, oauth, flask, wrapper

I am working on a Flask based OAuth project that has a single instance of `OAuthSignIn` class. This class has three subclasses for each OAuth client I support, Facebook, Twitter, and Google. There is only one instance of each on the server and they all contain an object called `oauth_session` used to make endpoint calls to the appropriate OAuth endpoint. To ensure these calls are on the behalf of the current user, before I make a call, I have to edit the `access_token` variable of the `oauth_session` object to the current user's `session['access_token']`. I want to do this via a wrapper found in the super class (OAuthObject).

The following is a very basic model of what I am doing on the server just show the inheritance of it and what not. I made a wrapper to do edit the subclass's `oauth_session.access_token` and threw that in the super class of `OAuthObect` so I only have to write it once.

```
from functools import wraps

class OAuthSessionObject():
  def __init__(self):
    self.access_token = "r424jt3g"

class OAuthObject():
  def __init__(self):
    pass

  def auth_request(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrapper(self):
      self.oauth_session.access_token = 444
      #self.oauth_session.access_token = session['access_token']
      return f(self)
    return wrapper


class GoogleObject(OAuthObject):
  def __init__(self):
    self.oauth_session = OAuthSessionObject()

  @OAuthObject.auth_request
  def make_request(self):
    print("Making a request with updated access_token:", self.oauth_session.access_token)

google = GoogleObject()
google.make_request()
```

#### Python 2 vs Python 3

Problem with this, it only [works](https://repl.it/Bcal) in Python 3, and I am currently running Python 2 server on heroku and locally, I get the following errors:

```
@OAuthSignIn.auth_request
TypeError: unbound method auth_request() must be called with OAuthSignIn instance as first argument (got function instance instead)
```

How can I make this work in Python 2??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Figured out the solution but need explanation:

All I had to do to get it to work in Python 2 was to modify the wrapper function to look like this:

```
@classmethod
def auth_request(self, f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrapper(self):
        self.oauth_session.access_token = session['access_token']
        return f(self)
    return wrapper
```

Had to make it a `@classmethod` and just add `self` as the first parameter to the `auth_request` declaration. Not sure why though, if someone would like to explain why this is treated differently between the two versions of Python that would be great.